# JavaScript Object to Array Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, object

I'm trying to handle a 2D Array to parse.

Results are coming from this piece of code;

```
var resultArray = $.parseJSON(result);
```

It appears like this;

[image]

I'm trying to parse this 2D Array by using this code;

```
resultArray[0][1];
```

...
...

But I am having this error;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Thank you for your help.

Update;

Result of console.log(resultArray);

[image]

Comment: Can you share result of `console.log(resultArray);` ?

Comment: please add the array and the wanted object in plain text.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: `resultArray[0][1]` is not parsing, it's property access.

Comment: @RobG So, how I can parse the value ?

Comment: `resultArray.MessageList.forEach(e  => e.forEach( i => console.log(i)));` might do the job.

Comment: Thank you @Redu, Now it works:)

Comment: The issue you have here is because your `resultArray` is not an array, it is an object. This object's `MessageList` property is an array. You can access it by going like so: `resultArray["MessageList"][0][1]` since what you have is an array that is a property of an object.